# Function to populate string array doesn't include the 0th element after called from main

Tags: c, c-strings

I have the following function which takes in a pointer to an array and populates it:

```
void parse(char *path, char *array[]){

    char *temp = malloc(sizeof(path));
    strcpy(temp, path);

    char *token = strtok(temp, "/");

    int i = 0;
    while(token != NULL){
        array[i++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }   
    free(temp);

}
```

Which is called from main like so:

```
...
char *array[3];
path = argv[1];
parse(path, array);
...
```

However, When I print the elements of the array from inside the parse function before it returns, I get the correct output, i.e. if the path is one/two/three/, it will output:

```
one
two
three
```

But If I print the elements of the array from main after calling parse(), the output doesn't contain the element at array[0]:

```
two
three
```

The code used the print the elements is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        printf("%s \n", array[i]);
    }
```

I figure there's something I'm missing related to C pointers or strings, since I don't understand why this is happening.

EDIT:  commenting out the line `free(temp)` fixed this issue, though why would this specifically affect the first item of the array and not the whole array?

Comment: That's because you freed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
char *temp = malloc(sizeof(path));
```

you're allocating the size of a pointer. Instead

```
char *temp = malloc(strlen(path)+1);
```

to allocate the size of the string pointed to by path (+1 for the trailing `\0`).

Reason: `strcpy(temp, path)` is likely to take more chars than the size of a pointer, which outcome in this case is undefined behavior.

Also, `strtok` returns pointers into `temp`, which is freed at the end of the function. Therefore, undefined behavior again.

So you better do the allocation of a temp string in main, then free it after use: in *main()*

```
char *array[3];
char *path = argv[1];
char *temp = malloc(strlen(path)+1);
strcpy(temp, path);

parse(temp, array);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
     printf("%s \n", array[i]);
}

free(temp);
```

And *parse()*

```
void parse(char *path, char *array[]){
    char *token = strtok(path, "/");

    int i = 0;
    while(token != NULL){
         printf("%s\n",token);
         array[i++] = token;
         token = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }   
}
```

You could also

- keep allocation of `temp` in `parse()`
- have `parse()` return `temp` (without freeing it)
- in `main()` you store that pointer in a variable `char *tobefree = parse(...);`
- then do the operations with `array`
- then `free(tobefree);`

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't chantge the output.  So far the only thing working is commenting out the `free(path);` which I'm guessing is a bad solution since it would cause a memory leak?

Comment: Added explanation and solution.